# Generate Azure Key Vault Certificate with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I want to generate a certificate in an Azure KeyVault using Bicep.
It's simple and straight forward to do in the Web UI and using azure-cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-create

But how do I do that with Bicep?

The only thing I found is this `resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-03-01'` but this actually wants to create a managed certificate and wants to bind it to some service, which I do not require.

How can I only generate the certificate in the key vault?

Comment: This is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above the @thomas said in some cases it will not support to generate certificate in key Vault using bicep.

Try the below code whether it works.

```
param  keyVaultName  string
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location

 
resource  keyVault  'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' = {
name: keyVaultName
location: location
sku : {
name: 'standard'
}
properties: {
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: []
    enabledForDeployment: false
    enabledForDiskEncryption: false
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: false
    enableSoftDelete: false
    enablePurgeProtection: false
    networkAcls: {
        bypass: 'AzureServices'
        defaultAction: 'Allow'
        }
    }
}


resource  certificate  'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/certificates@2021-06-01-preview' = {
    parent: keyVault
    name: 'my-certificate'
    properties: {
        certificatePolicy: {
        issuerParameters: {
        name: 'Unknown'
        }
    keyProperties: {
        keyType: 'RSA'
        keySize: 2048
        reuseKey: false
        }
    secretProperties: {
        contentType: 'application/x-pkcs12'
        }
        x509CertificateProperties: {
            subject: 'CN=my-certificate'
            validityInMonths: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find information about the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/certificates@2021-06-01-preview`?  I don't see any information about it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2021-06-01-preview/vaults

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it is not supported in bicep yet. (March 25. 2023)

There is another workaround using deployment scripts mentioned in [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/10044#discussioncomment-5424024)

Comment: could you expand? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587